# XSL concatenation with nested if conditions

Tags: xslt

I have following xml

```
<string1>Y</string1>
<string2>aaabbbcccddd</string2>
<string3>I have to concatentate this</string3>
```

I have to concatenate those three elements as follows.
If flag Y exists for string1 then hard code 'Flag Y exists' + string2 (if exists) + string3.
Please help me with the xsl phrase
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a need for nesting here:

```
<xsl:if test="string1='Y'">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Flag Y exists', string2, string3)"/>
</xsl:if>
```

---

> Those three are working, but now in xml i have additional
>   `<string4>string4</string4>`. <s>which also should be added to the
>   concatenation, but</s> only if it is not empty. If this condition is
>   matched then the hard code 'string4 is not empty' should be added
>
> Here the nesting is needed I suppose...

Yes, but it's fairly trivial:

```
<xsl:if test="string1='Y'">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Flag Y exists', string2, string3)"/>
    <xsl:if test="string(string4)">string4 is not empty</xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: OK, thank you, but how about string2. It should be concatenated only if exists

Comment: @MarcinSokołowski If it doesn't exist, then nothing (an empty string) will be concatenated in its place. Try it.

Comment: Those three are working, but now in xml i have additional <string4>string4</string4>. which also should be added to the concatenation, but only if it is not empty. If this condition is matched then the hard code 'string4 is not empty' should be added

Comment: Yes, but... I think i mentioned that not clear. <string4> should not been concatenated itself, but only if it is not empty, it should be hard code 'string4 is not null' just after <string3>

Comment: @MarcinSokołowski I am not entirely with you. Should `string4` itself be output if it is not empty? If yes, the above answer stands. If not, remove it from the `concatenate()` formula.

Comment: no, if on the input side (xml file) <string4> contains any value, then hard code 'String4 is not empty' should be included in the concat formula, just after string3

Comment: @MarcinSokołowski I have edited my answer accordingly.  Note that you don't need to put everything inside the concatenate() function.